# How to proceed with the following matrix problem

Tags: matrix

[image]

What will be the first step of the problem. I am not able to start the mentioned problem. I just want the starting hint to solve the mentioned problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need help to begin solving the problem, here's how I would start:
1) Take 2/5 common from the right hand side of the given equation.
2) Take it to the left hand side, which would look like P/(2/5), leaving the left hand side with the same vector as on the right.
3) Now, since P/(2/5) * [some vector] = [same vector], P/(2/5) should be a 3x3 identity matrix.
4) Evaluate the equation and find out the value of P and then choose the answer option which evaluates to true.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you don’t forget to upvote. Thanks!